# Isotope filtering - abnormal spacing on loading only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-isotope

I'm doing some maintenance on a PHP website that uses Isotope filtering, and I'm still learning Javascript.  Because of this, I'm having trouble figuring out how to fix a problem with Isotope.

I have a page with 40 tiles in two separate sections.  One of the sections works fine with no errors.  But in the second section, when I load the page, it displays the last 10-12 tiles on top of each other (it varies, seemingly randomly).

However, whenever I click any of the filters, it works fine, and pushes them out to the proper spacing.  So, the issue is only on the behavior during the initial load of the page.

Does anyone know what might be causing this sort of problem?

Comment: Very hard to tell without seeing any code but I would guess that you aren't waiting for the images to be loaded before using Iosotope. This will mean that isotope can calulate the wrong height for your elements. See here http://isotope.metafizzy.co/appendix.html

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I guess more than anything I needed help figuring out where to start looking.  This brings me a lot closer than I was.

It's definitely mis-calculating the distance between the pictures, that much I can tell.  I will update this once I test out the fix your link suggested.

Comment: seems like your images didn't get loaded so since they calculate your position exactly, without the image loaded means it has no width and height, which is the cause of why it is ontop of eachother, you can use the check if the images are loaded or when doc.ready

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing `document.ready` to `window.load`, which will make it wait for images to download before running isotope.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // executes when HTML-Document is loaded and DOM is ready
  $.isotope();
});

$(window).load(function() {
  // executes when complete page is fully loaded, including all frames, objects and images
 $.isotope();
});
```

Actually, reading the link 3rror404 posted, you can do

```
// layout Isotope again after all images have loaded
$container.imagesLoaded( function() {
  $container.isotope('layout');
});
```

Comment: This has me pointed in the right direction.  It's basically what I need, I'm just not sure exactly how to implement it, but I guess I'll get it figured out eventually.